# Angular : After a post request is made, how to trigger a get request and update a component with the modified values?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

`getAllSchools()` returns a list of schools from the backend. When app loads, I make a get request and loads the list of schools to an array called schools.

`addSchool()` adds a new school

Each time `addSchool()` is done, I want to refresh schools array to include the new school. How do I do this?

**school-service.ts**

```
  getAllSchools(): Observable<ISchool[]> {
    return this.http.get<ISchool[]>(this.url);
  }


  addSchool(school: ISchool): Observable<ISchool> {
    this.schoolsSubject$.next();
    return this.http.post<ISchool>(this.url, school, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    });
  }
```

**app-component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSchools();
  }


  getSchools(): void {
    this.schoolService.getAllSchools().subscribe({
      next: schools => {
        this.schools = schools;
        this.filteredSchools = schools;
      },
      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    });
  }
```

**add-scshool-component.ts**

```
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.schoolService.addSchool(this.model)
      .subscribe(
        (data: ISchool) => console.log(data),
        (err: any) => console.log(err)
      ); 
  }
```

Comment: Is add-school-component.ts child of app-component.ts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BehaviorSubject` to keep the data and `tap` to call again

```
export class YourService {
  private _schools: BehaviorSubject<ISchool[]>;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
    this._schools = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  }

  getAllSchools(): Observable<ISchool[]> {
    this._getAllSchools();

    return this._schools.asObservable();
  }

  addSchool(school: ISchool): Observable<ISchool> {
    return this.http.post<ISchool>(this.url, school, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }).pipe(
      // after successfully adding a school you call once again get all schools
      tap(() => this._getAllSchools()),
    );
  }

  private _getAllSchools(): void {
    this.http.get<ISchool[]>(this.url).subscribe(
      schools => this._schools.next(schools),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in add-school-component.ts

```
  @Output() newSchool: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.newSchool.emit(this.model);
  }
```

in app-component.html

```
<app-add-school (newSchool)='addNewSchool($event)></app-add-school>
```

in app-conponent.ts

```
  addNewSchool(newSchool) {
    this.schoolService.addSchool(newSchool)
       .subscribe(
         (data: ISchool) => console.log(data),
         (err: any) => console.log(err)
       );

       this.getSchools();
  }
```

Comment: schools array is the app component and addschool is in the schools-service. So, can't do that..